# $_POST not working on Bluesnap Hosted Payment Fields

Tags: field, payment, hosted, bluesnap

I have a problem to GET the value of cardholder name using  $_POST['name input']

$_POST['name input'] always return empty

Can anyone please help me to get the cardholder name value from Bluesnap Hosted Payment Fields

Answer (score 1):

Cardholder name should be your own field on your page. Bluesnap hosted payment fields only include the sensitive payment information (CC number, CVV, expiration date)

Comment: Thank you so much this is strange but how can I collect the zip code for example and cardholder name from the input using PHP !! I am using the Card form from bluesnap you can find here https://developers.bluesnap.com/docs/build-a-form

Comment: It would be a regular form like any other form you would have, it's not related to bluesnap. So you would have an HTML form that includes the cardholder name, zip code, any other info you might need, and I would also suggest having a hidden field that will store the bluesnap token ID. Then you submit the form to your server and parse it in your PHP code.

Comment: What about storing the token on session variable

Comment: That is also ok.

Comment: Great. The form of Bluesnap Hosted Payment Fields not posting data, I've added holder input on a <fieldset> the $_POST works perfectly thank you so much :)